# De-glitching overlapping windows

Tags: codenameone, display

If I create multiple overlapping windows (ie; like on a real computer's desktop) the redisplay is very glitchy.  Each window paints back-to-front,
resulting in the right final picture but with lots of unpleasant intermediate
states.

Is this an artifact of the simulator environment, or does it reflect
the reality of the target platforms?

Answer (score 0):

If "scrollable" is checked then you should get a pretty accurate representation of the device. Otherwise you might get glitches.

Do you use this effect by layering dialogs one on top of the other?

That's highly discouraged and we'd strongly recommend against doing that as the painting performance will be pretty slow and might introduce issues.

Comment: I use a single com.codename1.ui.Form with containers laid out inside it in a style similar to desktops, which can include overlapping.  In my use, its not necessary that the overlap be high performance, but it is necessary that it be graceful.   The simple way to deal with this is to allocate yet-another full screen bitmap to paint into.

Comment: Painting in Codename One is double buffered so if you are seeing glitches in cases like that I'm guessing you are calling repaint while changing data or doing something outside of the EDT